# Calculating sample size to power 3x2 chi square, retrospective cross sectional study

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, statistical-power, ordinal-data

I need to calculate the sample size for a retrospective, cross sectional study.

The outcome variable is fear of cancer recurrence and has 3 categories (normal, mild, significant). There are two groups (treatment vs no treatment).
I want to conduct a 3x2 chi square.

There is very little existing data on this population with the fear of cancer recurrence measure we are using and also, very little data on the fear of cancer recurrence measure in treatment vs no treatment in other populations. so effect size is likely to be ard to calculate, but I guess we could assume small.
I can get rough estimates of the proportion of patients who score in these categories in another sample, but not stratified by treatment vs no treatment.

How can I calculate the sample size needed? what information do I need? where do I start?